# how to run/start VBA program mac excel 2011

Tags: excel, macos, vba

I am new to VBA programing and want to practice on my mac. However, it appears that the bar that was on the top of my excel document where I start/run the program by pressing a play button has disappeared. Now I can't run my programs anymore simply because the bar I used before to start the program is gone. Would deeply appreciate help with getting that toolbar up again. Alternatively, what is the command for running a vba program on mac? On pc it's F9, F5. Anything similar?

Answer (score 6):

Get to the Macro Editor:

```
Tools -> Macro -> Visual Basic Editor
```

From here, while this is active:

```
View --> Toolbars --> Standard
```